# Error: Objects are not valid as a React Child

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display an object if the condition is false for which I was doing something like this in my stateful component return statement.

```
{ !this.state.searchCoin ?   {displayCrypto}   : null }
```

For this, it is throwing the following error

> Objects are not valid as a React Child

My display crypto looks something like this (called in render)

```
let displayCrypto = CryptoData.map(el => {
    return (<CoinCard
       no={i++}
       key={el["short"]}
       coinShortName = {el["short"]}
       coinName = {el["long"]}
       coinPrice = {el["price"].toFixed(2)}
       marketCap = {(el["mktcap"]/1000000000).toFixed(4)}
       percentChange = {el["perc"].toFixed(2)}
       vwapData={el["vwapData"].toFixed(2)}
      />
```

**[Question:]** How can we I use itinerary expression to display on object if the condition is false?

Ps: If you are downvoting this question then please leave a comment as well so that I can improve my question as well.

Comment: You might want to include some more code for context. Where is `i` or `el` coming from in `displayCrypto`

Comment: remove the `{}` -> `{ !this.state.searchCoin ?   displayCrypto   : null }`

Comment: @OzzyWalsh `i` is just variable which is incrementing its value. `el` is from map function

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Your comment just made me realize my mistake and solved my issue as well. Share it in answer and I will mark it answered. Thanks a lot champ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `{}` : `{ !this.state.searchCoin ? displayCrypto : null }`

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping the `cryptoCoinCard` components in brackets this prompts the error.

Remove the `{}` and it should work.

```
{ !this.state.searchCoin ? displayCrypto : null }
```